# How to specify external YAML configuration file for springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to pass in a value to be autowired from a custom configuration file in Spring boot. Below are code snippets:

***Spring class***

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Value("${BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS}")
    private String bootstrapServers;
```

***myfile.yaml***

```
BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 
  10.0.0.12:9092
```

***Execution command***

```
java  -jar app.jar --spring.config.location=/file/path/myfile.yaml
```

However when I type the above command I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS' in value "${BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS}"

What am I missing here in order to get this to work? I intend to mount the app in kubernetes so I need to be able to externalize my configuration. Thanks in advance.

Comment: first thing I would try would be using bootstrap.servers in your code and bootstrap: servers in the yaml (bootstrap and servers on seperate lines). That BOOTSTRAP_SEVRVERS form could cause confusion with env var form

Comment: After that I'd try setting a standard property like spring.application.name and then try properties instead of yaml. If that doesn't pin it down then try using the standard /config external config path instead of specifying explicitly. Note that you can use env vars instead of mounting if you want to. I discuss this in https://dzone.com/articles/hunting-treasure-with-kubernetes-configmaps-and-se if it helps

Comment: I am not sure of this because right now I can not perform a quick test but I would suggest you to change to `BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "10.0.0.12:9092"` because it may be interpreting as `BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS.10.0.0.12` with the value `9092`

Comment: can you try this format `BOOTSTRAP.SERVERS: 10.0.0.12:9092`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently it is due to invalid path declaration, to configure external properties/yml files you must use `file:` prefix for `--spring.config.location`.

So try this,

```
--spring.config.location="file:/path/to/myfile.yaml"
```

An alternative would be,

```
-Dspring.config.location="file:/path/to/myfile.yaml"
```

Make sure `myfile.yaml` is in the directory.

---

Official documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

Comment: do you have a github project you can share addressing the following solution?

Comment: @bijayshrestha not at the movement